# Parsing Nested Elements HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl

I have an example html:

```
<div>
    <p>get this</p>
</div>
<p>not this</p>
```

Is there a way to get the nested element using `HTML::TreeBuilder` and `look_down`? I can use `look_down` on the resulting element of the first search.

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->parse("<div><p>get this</p></div><p>not this</p>");
my $div = $tree->look_down(_tag => "div");
my $p = $div->look_down(_tag => "p");
print $p->as_text() . "\n";
```

Is it possible to get this in a single search, similar to the css selector `div p`? Am I limited to XPath?

Comment: Why do you want to use look_down?In that case, xpath or css selectors would be convenient. If you use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath, then you can do `my $p = $tree->findnodes('//div/p')->[0];`. And if you prefer HTML::TreeBuilder::Select : `my $p = ($tree->select('div p'))[0];`.

Comment: What originally drew me to `look_down` is the speed performance vs. XPath. I found it's 7 times slower on my machine using this script: https://gist.github.com/dsullivan7/6d039fda561d6bf4d55e4b8fd8f7a6c3

Answer (score 1):

You can `look_up` form all `p`'s to see whether they're contained in a `div`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

sub paragraph_whose_ancestor_is_div {
    my $node = shift;
    return 'p' eq $node->{_tag} && $node->look_up(_tag => 'div')
}

my $tree = 'HTML::TreeBuilder'->new;
$tree->parse("<html><div><p>get this</p></div><p>not this</p></html>");

my @p = $tree->look_down(\&paragraph_whose_ancestor_is_div);

say $_->as_text() for @p;
```

Comment: That's really just doing what the OP suggested but backwards and hiding the second search inside a subroutine. You're also checking whether any *ancestor* is a `div` instead of just the *parent*. The answer is that, no, there's no one-step solution

Comment: To check just the parent, you can use `'div' eq ($node->lineage_tag_names)[0]` instead. I agree that it's not ideal (I like XPath more).

Comment: Yes, and thankfully the DOM seems to be dying except for LibXML. CSS has an advantage over XPath for HTML5 in that it will parse space-separated `class` attribute values, but maybe XPath 2 does that?

Comment: @Borodin What do you mean by "the DOM seems to be dying" ?

Comment: @CJ7: What I meant was that using the Document Object Model as a technique for accessing specific parts of HTML (and XML) is getting less popular. XPath and CSS selectors are much more expressive. And I apologise—you're right, I chose a very obscure way of phrasing  that.

Comment: @Borodin: Isn't XPath a way to query the DOM? :-)

Comment: @choroba: [XPath](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is a way to access the *document*. The [DOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is an API for navigating and modifying the document tree.